# MySQL getting followers from a certain user in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

My database currently exists of 2 tables. One is a user table, and the other is a followers table. Users can follow each other, which means the followers table will have a row that looks like this:

```
Table: followers
Row: user_id | follower_id
```

So if I have 3 users:

```
User 1 | id = 1
User 2 | id = 2
User 3 | id = 3
```

And user 1 follows user 2 and user 2 follows user 3, the rows in the followers table will look like this:

```
user_id = 2 | follower_id = 1
user_id = 3 | follower_id = 2
```

All of this works fine, but how should I create a query when I want to retrieve all followers from this user in c#? My class has a list of ids of people who follow this user. Like this: (This could be a list of user objects, I just need the ids for now)

```
public class User
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<int> followers { get; set; }
}
```

I can retrieve the user from the database, I just can't figure out how to get the followers of this user all in one query. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You want all distinct followers or list of followers for a specific user. If later is the case, your class should give you the list. If I have understood is rightly...

Comment: `I want to retrieve all followers from this user in c#` Which user?

Comment: In SQL this is done using a JOIN between the user table and the followers table. Are you looking for the query text to use?

Comment: A simple query with an appropriate `where` clause should do the trick.

Comment: @Steve if you could, yes. I don't know how to put these ids in the list of the user

Comment: @Gavin for example, user 2. Really just a query where I can get the followers from any user

Comment: @Shadow how would this query look like? And how would I get these values and put them in a list in c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query could look like this:

```sql
SELECT u.id, u.name, GROUP_CONCAT(f.follower_id) AS list_of_followers
FROM user u
JOIN followers f ON u.id = f.user_id
WHERE u.id = 2 
GROUP BY u.id, u.name
```

`list_of_followers` is just a comma-separated list of all followers of user with `id=2`. You can easily parse the string and populate a `List<int>` out of it.

**Edit:**

If you want to also get users with *no* followers, then you can modify the above query as follows:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(f.follower_id) AS list_of_followers,
       COUNT(f.follower_id) AS count_of_followers
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN followers f ON u.id = f.user_id
WHERE u.id = 2 
GROUP BY u.id, u.name
```

For users with no followers `count_of_followers = 0`.

Comment: Okay quick question, I want to use this query to retrieve users who don't have followers too. When I try to do so, it returns null. Is this fixable?